# Is it possible to have content width set to 100% in the meta tag

Tags: android, html, css, width, meta

Is it possible to have content width set to 100% in the meta tag. For instance  instead of a fixed with in pixels. I want to render my page on any screen including mobile devices. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: why.. css didn't help you?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. :) Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question could use more detail: please show a code example illustrating what you've tried, explaining what that code did, and how the result is different from what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set content percentages in your metatags. The way to responsive design is firstly:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And secondly with media queries:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
   div {
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Where `max-width` is width of the screen that you want the media query to kick in, and the `div` is an example of the css 'nesting' that you'll need to preform.

Note, you'll probably need to create 3 or 4 different media queries so the site looks right in widescreen, normal, tablet, and mobile.